# Java. difficulty to call a method from an objet. (beginner)

Tags: java

I hope you are well.
I am a beginner in Java.

My issue is I cannot reach the method `talk()` from the class GuessGame and I wonder why.

***Here the code from the class where I am calling the method `talk()`:***

```
package guessGame;

public class GuessGame {
    
    void guessGameStarts(){
    System.out.println("    Welcome to a new party of GuessGame! \n We have 4 news cantidates for this session!\n");
    }
    
    Player player1 = new Player("Maurisse");
    Player player2 = new Player("Albert");
    Player player3 = new Player("Mathilde");
    Player player4 = new Player("Chloé");
    
    player1.talk();
}
```

***Here the class where the method talk() is implemented:***

```
package guessGame;

public class Player {
    
    private String name;
    
    Player(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public void talk() {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

The error given by Eclipse for the line `player1.talk()` is : Syntax error on token "talk", Identifier expected after this token.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: You call the method outside of other methods. move the line `player1.talk()` into `guessGameStarts`

Comment: Your Player code needs to be inside of a method.

Comment: So kind of you! Thanks a million!

Comment: Try looking for "java class structure" to learn how basic java program should look. As @Jens said you are putting body of a method/constructor right into class which is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to execute code in the context the class is being loaded. To do that, you'd have to use a `static` code block. Still, this is not the solution you want. What you probably want is for that code to execute in the `guessGameStarts` method:

```java
public class GuessGame {
    
    void guessGameStarts() {
        System.out.println("    Welcome to a new party of GuessGame! \n We have 4 news cantidates for this session!\n");
    
    
        Player player1 = new Player("Maurisse");
        ...
    
        player1.talk();
    }
}
```

Indenting your code is really important to improve readability. If you had intended the code inside `guessGameStarts` (which was just a simple print statement), you would have seen your code was outside this method.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is misplaced.
It should be like:

`class GuessGame`:

```
package guessGame;

public class GuessGame {

    void guessGameStarts(){
        System.out.println("    Welcome to a new party of GuessGame! \n We have 4 news cantidates for this session!\n");

        Player player1 = new Player("Maurisse");
        Player player2 = new Player("Albert");
        Player player3 = new Player("Mathilde");
        Player player4 = new Player("Chloé");
        player1.talk();
    }
}
```

`class Player`:

```
package guessGame;

public class Player {
    private String name;
    Player(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void talk() {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```